# Dynamic from first to the last cell

Tags: excel, vba

I want to get all the cells for ID, but the tool will work for lots of users and it might be another column number for every of them, so it can't be hardcoded.

So far I came up with idea to count column of desired ID column (it will always have the same name - ID)

```
    col = 1
    Do Until Name = "ID"
        Name = Cells(1, col)
        col = col + 1
    Loop
ID = col - 1

Debug Print N_ID
```

However I don't know how to get row depending on which column number is ID. Like if ID column number is 3 then it goes from C1 to the last, if 5 then E1 and so on

I've got it like that

```
n_copy_range = Range(Rows.Count, ID).End(xlUp)
```

but obviously it gets me an error because VBA dont know where to start rows count and it gets ridiculous amount of rows (because I don't know either which column number ID would be), the column number works well due to counting I've presented above

Comment: use `c=application.match("ID",rows(1),0)` to get the column number and then `set n_copy_range=range(cells(1,c),Range(Rows.Count, c).End(xlUp))`.

Comment: I keep getting error 1004 'range' of object '_Global failed' even tho I've set n_copy_range as Long or Range, any suggestion?

Tried to get it previously several times but always had the same error

Comment: Why would you set it as a Long?

Comment: Tried just to make it work. It does not work as long/integer/range, it does not work if its just "set" or without set, anything I try to use has the same error in the rows.count part

Comment: I've overcome it by doing
Cells(1, c).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select

However I've read that it is not very efficient solution so I try to omitt that